# Bigcommerce API - Option default value

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to set the default value for a "multi-line text" option via the Bigcommerce API? Currently I have not found a way to do it.

Here's the documentation for the Options resource:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/options

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [option value object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/option_value) to set a default value

Comment: But what about for a multi-line text field option? I don't think this will work.

Comment: Yes, you can not create values for multi-line text field options. I just tested to confirm. Is there any way to set the default value for this type of option?

Comment: Through the control panel until we make an update to the API (which is being discussed).